# Utilising assignment for thesis

Tags: ethics, plagiarism, self-plagiarism

I had utilized an assignment that was under a free license to explain a part of my thesis but did not self-plagiarize by copying my own written work for an earlier submission.

Is it acceptable?

Comment: A thesis is a publication. If the material is new and is not published anywhere (preferably even in pre-print servers) then it should be fine. Provided all the work is yours and not someone else's assignment. There really is no way to know but think of it as self morality!

Comment: What do you mean, exactly by "utilized an assignment"? Was it the assignment statement or the solution? If it was the solution, did you write it? If you wrote it, is your solution "published" in some form - even just on a web site?

Comment: The assignment was a set of tasks that were experiments, the set of tasks and their perception can change according to people. Set of tasks were under a free license. I wrote two different solutions (with changes in langaugaes). This was utilized as an introduction only and were not a major part of thesis

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure that I understand the entire scenario, so this will be a bit hypothetical.

If you write something but it isn't published in any form then, later, you can simply copy and publish any part of it without citation or further comment. It isn't self plagiarism to use your own unpublished work.

Assignments in a course might, however, follow some rules beyond those generally accepted in scholarship. If the thesis is at the same institution as the earlier coursework, then, for purposes of keeping the faculty happy, it would probably be wise to mention that some of what you write was written earlier for a course.

But normally, student work for course assignments isn't really published, though it is shared in a limited way (with the professor). There can be exceptions, of course.

A way to be safe with all sorts of plagiarism, including self plagiarism is to cite if there is any doubt at all. Over citation will not, generally, be a problem. Under citation can be.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it really helps. The assignment was created by a third party and they have made it accessible to all under GPL and is commonly used by many universities. I utilized that assignment to explain some concepts and wrote them differently from my original assignment.

Comment: Just cite it and you should be fine.